# Set of solutions to $f''(x) + 3f'(x) +x^2f(x)= \sin(x)$ a subspace of $F$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Determine whether the set of solutions to the differential equation $f''(x) + 3f'(x) +(x^2)f(x)=\sin(x)$ is a subspace of $F$.

1. I tested whether the subspace was empty by subbing in $x=0$. Is this correct or am I meant to sub in $f(x)=0$ because when I do that I get $\sin(x)=0$ and hence the solution is not a subspace as it is empty.

What should I do now?

Comment: Is the solution set closed under scalar multiplication? And your solution set should be a set of functions, not numbers! So you could try $f(x)=0$, not $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **homogeneous** linear (differential) equation, then the set of solutions is a vector space, for the sum of two solutions is a solution, and a constant times a solution is a solution.

But this is not the case for an **inhomogeneous** linear equation. The quickest proof is that the identically $0$ function, which is in **any** vector space of functions, is not a solution of our inhomogeneous linear equation, or indeed of any inhomogeneous linear equation.